# How to create Dynamic Web API Controllers for services in different assemblies?

Tags: c#, castle-windsor, .net-assembly, asp.net-boilerplate

I'm trying to create Dynamic Web Api Controlers for services in my `ThirdParty` assembly, as well as controllers for the services in my `SimpleTaskSystem` assembly, with the following:

```
[DependsOn(typeof(AbpWebApiModule))] //We declare depended modules explicitly
public class SimpleTaskSystemWebApiModule : AbpModule
{
    public override void Initialize()
    {
        IocManager.RegisterAssemblyByConvention(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

        IocManager.RegisterAssemblyByConvention(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(ThirdPartyApplicationModule)));

        DynamicApiControllerBuilder
            .For<ITaskAppService>("tasksystem/task")
            .Build();

        // this works when I call
        // /api/services/eggsystem/egg/GetEggs
        DynamicApiControllerBuilder 
            .For<IEggAppService>("eggsystem/egg")
            .ForMethod("GetEggs").WithVerb(HttpVerb.Get)
            .Build();

        // When doesn't work when I try to call
        // /api/services/fleasystem/flea/GetFleas
        DynamicApiControllerBuilder
          .For<IFleaAppService>("fleasystem/flea")
          .ForMethod("GetFleas").WithVerb(HttpVerb.Get)
          .Build();
    }
}
```

I'm getting the following error when I try to call

```
/api/services/fleasystem/flea/GetFleas
```

Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.HandlerException occurred
Message: A first chance exception of type 'Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.HandlerException' occurred in Castle.Windsor.dll
Additional information: Can't create component 'ThirdParty.Application.Fleas.FleaAppService' as it has dependencies to be satisfied.

'ThirdParty.Application.Fleas.FleaAppService' is waiting for the following dependencies:

- Service 'ThirdParty.Core.Fleas.IFleaRepository' which was not registered.
- Service 'Abp.Domain.Repositories.IRepository`1[[ThirdParty.Core.Dogs.Dog, ThirdParty.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' which was not registered.

Both `FleaAppService` (and all related classes to `Flea`) follow the exact same pattern as the `EggAppService`. The only difference is `EggAppService` exists in the same assembly as the `TaskAppService`

What do I need to do to create a dynamic web api controllers to services in other assemblies?

**Update**

For the record, as far as I can see I'm registering the missing dependencies. My `ThirdPartyApplicationModule` is defined as

```
namespace ThirdParty.Application
{
    /// <summary>
    /// 'Application layer module' for this project.
    /// </summary>
    [DependsOn(typeof(ThirdPartyCoreModule), typeof(AbpAutoMapperModule))]
    public class ThirdPartyApplicationModule : AbpModule
    {
        public override void Initialize()
        {
            //This code is used to register classes to dependency injection system for this assembly using conventions.
            IocManager.RegisterAssemblyByConvention(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

            //We must declare mappings to be able to use AutoMapper
            DtoMappings.Map();
        }
    }
}
```

and `ThirdPartyCoreModule` is defined as

```
namespace ThirdParty.Core
{
    /// <summary>
    /// 'Core module' for this project.
    /// </summary>
    public class ThirdPartyCoreModule : AbpModule
    {
        public override void Initialize()
        {
            //This code is used to register classes to dependency injection system for this assembly using conventions.
            IocManager.RegisterAssemblyByConvention(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to register the missing dependencies, as the message says.

Comment: How do I register those dependencies?

Comment: https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/installers.md

Comment: I don't know what `AbpModule` is and `IocManager` but it looks like some sort of wrapper around the container. Whatever that comes from probably is the source of your problem

Comment: It's all asp.net boilerplate stuff.

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell the ABP Framework explicitly that the `SimpleTaskSystemWebApiModule` depends on the `ThirdPartyApplicationModule`.

Changing this line:

```
[DependsOn(typeof(AbpWebApiModule))] //We declare depended modules explicitly
```

to this:

```
[DependsOn(typeof(AbpWebApiModule), typeof(ThirdPartyApplicationModule))] //We declare depended modules explicitly
```

should do the trick